# Категории custom post type wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

Я использую для создания кастомных записей и таксономии `CPT UI` плагин и для категории использую `Categories (WP Core)` , но у меня , когда открываешь записи , нету сбоку списка категории, где я могу присоединить запись к определенной категории. Как можно добавить ? повторюсь , я использую `Categories (WP Core)`  и мне надо только это использовать.

Answer (score 0):

Категории работают только с пост типом пост. Если вам для кастомного типа постов нужны категории добавляйте новую таксономию.

Comment: таксономию я добавил, но вот мне надо было сделать фильтрацию по категориям и тд , почему то не выводило и тому подобное, так что пришлось использовать WP category core и всё получилось , но вот просто не могу добавлять нормально эти категории, так как их сбоку нет